# Time complexity analysis for a while loop with a cubed iterator

Tags: algorithm, time, while-loop, complexity-theory

I am trying to analyze the time complexity of the following algorithm:

```
Algorithm WhileLoop2(n):
    x = 0
    j = 3
    while(j <= n)
        x = x + 1
        j = j * j * j
    return x
```

I think that while it's looping, j will be 3j, 9j, 27j,... but I'm not sure what complexity that would correlate to. I have heard that it is O(loglogn) but I am not sure how to check it or how to get to that point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `j` will be 3, 27, 19683.. You are multiplying. Not adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm will iterate as long as the condition is fulfilled: `j <= n`. So it stops when `j > n`. So it will iterate with `j =`

- 3
- 27 (3^3)
- 19683 (27^3 = 3^(3^3))
- ...

so the last `j` is equal to `3^(3^i)` where `i` is the iteration count. So when the algorithm stops we have: `3^3^i > n`.Taking `log(3)` from both sides we get: `3^i > log(3)(n)`. Taking the `log(3)` again we get: `i > log(3)(log(3)(n))`. So indeed it's `O(loglogn)`.

Comment: Thank you! It makes a lot more sense now.